# VBA Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed

Tags: excel, vba

The error "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed" appears on this line of my code:

```
Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, CustCol).Value).Value = Sheet2.Cells(CltRow, CustCol).Value
```

I tried fixing it by adding the `Sheet2.` because the `with` block is set to Sheet1. But the error still shows. I want to retrieve the information in the rows of Sheet2 to show in Sheet1

> `Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, CustCol).Value).Value = Sheet2.Cells(CltRow, CustCol).Value`

This is my code

```
Option Explicit
Sub Customer_Load()
Dim CltRow As Long, LastRepRow As Long, CustCol As Long
With Sheet1
    If .Range("B6").Value = Empty Then
        MsgBox "Por favor, seleccione un cliente"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    CltRow = .Range("B6").Value
    
    'Clear Existing Data
    .Range("E4:G4,E6:G6,E8:G8,E10:G10,E12:G12,J4:L4, J6:L6,J8:L8,J10:L10,J12:L12").ClearContents 'Clear Customer Cells
    .Range("D17:I45").ClearContents 'Clear All Other Fields
    
    For CustCol = 1 To 12
        Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, CustCol).Value).Value = Sheet2.Cells(CltRow, CustCol).Value
    Next CustCol
    
    .Shapes("ExistCustGrp").Visible = msoCTrue
    .Shapes("NewCustGrp").Visible = msoFalse
    .Shapes("ExistRepGrp").Visible = msoCTrue
    .Shapes("NewRepBtn").Visible = msoFalse
    
    'Load Parts
    LastRepRow = Sheet3.Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row
    Sheet3.Range("A2:F2" & LastRepRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, 
    CriteriaRange:=Sheet3.Range("G2:G3"), CopyToRange:=Sheet3.Range("I2:M2"), Unique:=False
              
    End With
  End Sub
```

I want the info in Sheet3 to show in the table of "Repuestos" in Sheet1, depending on the ID of the customer in Sheet2, so if the ID is "1" show the info in Sheet3 of the customer with ID 1.

Comment: Your are using the .Value property of a range object as the argument for a range object. 
 Try `.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, CustCol).Value).Value` =>`.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, CustCol)).Value`

Comment: Does `Sheet2.Cells(1, CustCol).Value` contain more than just a cell reference, e.g. `Sheet1!$a$5` ?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I tried it, but it still shows the same error. Just that now the error appears to be in the line with code `.Range("E4:G4, E6:G6, E8:G8, E10:G10, E12:G12, J4:L4, J6:L6,J 8:L8, J10:L10, J12:L12").ClearContents 'Clear Customer Cells`

Comment: Could you share the contents of the cells `A1:L1` of `Sheet2`? BTW, change `J 8` to `J8`.

Comment: Could you also give some details about the sheet (and workbook) too? Are they protected? Are they visible?

Comment: @Ambie I'm not quite sure how to make sure if it's visible or protected, but I'm assuming it's not protected and it's visible.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I changed the `J 8` to `J8` and it fixed it, but it went back to the other line of code, do you think it might be another syntax error? That is keeping the error?

Comment: You need to show us `Sheet1` and `Sheet3` (the screenshots) and explain what needs to be written (copied) and where to. `Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(1, CustCol).Value).Value` boils down to `Sheet2.Range("Requestos").Value` and `Sheet2.Range("").Value` which doesn't make sense and causes the error.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I've added the screenshots for all of the sheets, what I'm trying to do is to take the ID of the customer which is in Sheet2, and compare it to the ID Column in Sheet3. If the IDs match, then I want to show the info from `Sheet3 A3:F` into `Sheet3 I3:M`